# Use jQuery's .wrap all children above element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following HTML:

```
<div class="main_container">
  <a href="#">Financial</a>
  <div class="sub_container">
    <a href="#">Financial services</a>
    <a href="#">Government</a>
  </div>
  <img class="image" src="img/img.png">
  <a href="#">Education</a>
  <div class="sub_container">
    <a href="#">Broadcast and media</a>
    <a href="#">Education</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Government</a>
  <div class="sub_container">
    <a href="#">Broadcast and media</a>
    <a href="#">Government</a>
  </div>
  <img class="image" src="img/img.png">
</div>
```

I.m trying to get wrap around all the elements above img tag, without results, i already try to use wrap, wrapAll, prevAll but those does not work.

Output code i'm trying to get:

```
<div class="main_container">

  <div class="WRAP_CONTAINER">
      <a href="#">Financial</a>
      <div class="sub_container">
        <a href="#">Financial services</a>
        <a href="#">Government</a>
      </div>
  </div>

  <img class="image" src="img/img.png">

  <div class="WRAP_CONTAINER">
      <a href="#">Education</a>
      <div class="sub_container">
        <a href="#">Broadcast and media</a>
        <a href="#">Education</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Government</a>
      <div class="sub_container">
        <a href="#">Broadcast and media</a>
        <a href="#">Government</a>
      </div>
  </div>

  <img class="image" src="img/img.png">
</div>
```

Please help, I'm starting to lose senses.

Comment: How does it help us help you if you don't provide any of your actual wrapping code?

Comment: use `prevUntil()` to get all elements above img tag up to another img tag

Answer (score 4):

this should do it

```
​$("img")​.each(function()
{
    $(this).prevUntil("img").wrapAll("<div class='WRAP_CONTAINER'></div>");
})​;​
```

Comment: Ilia G, Thanks a loot, this do exactly what i need!